# Lights go out or go off?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I don't understand why they say "One by one, the street lights went out leaving us in total darkness." Why there can't be "...the street lights went off..."?
I have looked it up in dictionary; "go out" means "stop shining" while "go off" means "stop working". So why there can't be "went off"? Anyone please help me!

Comment: More than possible : http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=lights+out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went out must come from when lights were candle or gas lighten - this the lights would `go out` as they couldn't exactly be *turned* off.

A candle needs to be 'put out' manually or would 'go out' by itself.

Term still applies today with things like power cuts or timed lighting.